# Make Python's argparse accept single-character abbreviations for subparsers?

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I'm using `argparse`'s excellent subparser system to make a command line program that accepts many different commands.  From what I read, `argparse` automatically accepts single-character abbreviations for arguments when they are unambiguous.  I want to make it do the same thing for subparsers.  If I set up my subparsers like this:

```
    foo_parser = subparsers.add_parser('foo')
    # ... set up arguments and handler ...

    bar_parser = subparsers.add_parser('bar')
    # ... set up arguments and handler ...
```

Then I'd like the parser to accept `myprogram f arg0` as an unambiguous abbreviation for `myprogram foo arg0`.  But it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From argparse documentation it is not clear that it supports such automatic abbreviation for subparser but you can explicitly set alias like this:

```
foo_parser = subparsers.add_parser('foo', aliases=['f'])
```

On the other hand, arguments abbreviation is [supported](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argument-abbreviations-prefix-matching).

Comment: This is what I needed, unfortunately it's only supported in Python 3.